# Seaborn doesn't show up in matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I was trying to put a seaborn plot in a matplotlib subplot. However this one does not show up.
Instead the python icon jump infinitely in the osx dock infinitely.

I tried as mentionned in other posts to call plt.show() but that does not change anything.

Here is the code of the plot:

```py
def plot(self):
  time_mesh_basic, basic_results = self.basic() # gives numpy ndarray
  time_mesh_stoch, stochastic_results = self.stochastic() # gives pandas Dataframe

  # 2 lines, 1 column
  fig, ((ax1), (ax2)) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(15, 7))
  fig.suptitle("Série temporelle")

  ax1.plot(time_mesh_basic, basic_results[:,0], color="black")
  ax1.plot(time_mesh_basic, basic_results[:,1], color="red")
  ax1.plot(time_mesh_basic, basic_results[:,2], color="gold")

  ax1.set_xlabel("$t$")
  ax1.set_ylabel("$x$, $y$, $z$")
  ax1.set_xlim(0,500)
  ax1.set_ylim(-7,7)
  ax1.legend(self.legends, loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5))
  ax1.set_title("Basique")

  # ax2.plot(time_mesh_stoch, stochastic_results[:,0], color="black")
  # ax2.plot(time_mesh_stoch, stochastic_results[:,1], color="red")
  # ax2.plot(time_mesh_stoch, stochastic_results[:,2], color="gold")

  # plot the mean of all the simulations
  # with a 95% CI interval
  print(stochastic_results.head())
  sns.lineplot(
    x="t",
    y="variables",
    hue="position",
    data=stochastic_results,
    ax=ax2
  )

  ax2.set_xlabel("$t$")
  ax2.set_ylabel("$x$, $y$, $z$")
  ax2.set_xlim(0,500)
  ax2.set_ylim(-5,5)
  ax2.legend(self.legends, loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5))
  ax2.set_title("Stochastique")

  plt.tight_layout()
  plt.show()
```

Here's the head of the data passed to seaborn:
[image: time-serie-stochastic]

A reproductible example can be found in this repo: https://github.com/Mathieu-R/climate-tipping-points using --plot=time-series

Comment: Without the data it is hard to guess what is going on. Does the code write out an error message= How does it look without `ax2.set_xlim(..)` and `ax2.set_ylim(...)`?

Comment: Agreed that it's difficult to answer without sample data. Since you're adding the legend in matplotlib, you may wish to specify `legend=False` in your call to `sns.lineplot()` to avoid any potential conflict there.

Comment: I added a link to my repo for a reproductible example. There's a lot going on before that plot function so it is hard to add everything in that post.

Comment: I downloaded your example. The problem is that calculating the confidence interval for so many data (1.5 million rows) takes a very long time.  You could try `sns.lineplot(..., n_boot=100)`. The default is `n_boot=1000` which takes 10 times longer to calculate.  Just be patient.